# Two different INSERT INTO statements that do the same thing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm digging into a legacy code (C++/Qt) which uses SQL(uses Oracle 11g) a lot. I've come with this piece of code(just changed variables name and write it in multiple lines for a better readability):

```
insert into FOO_TABLE (BEGIN, FIRST_VALUE, SECOND_VALUE, VALUE, BAR) select 
999, 
D.FIRST, 
(select O.SECOND from TABLE_TWO O where O.ID=555), 
333, 
444 
from TABLE_ONE D where D.ID=666
```

This in the form of **`INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`**

Now it seems here **"select"** is used together with insert to retreive and create a row with a **single line**. However the syntax seems awkward. I changed it to:

```
insert into FOO_TABLE (BEGIN, FIRST_VALUE, SECOND_VALUE, VALUE, BAR) values (
999, 
(select D.FIRST from TABLE_ONE D where D.ID=666), 
(select O.SECOND from TABLE_TWO O where O.ID=555), 
333, 
444)
```

And this one works without any problem. This is in the form of **`INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...`**

Is there any difference in terms of performance or anything else? Because the second line seems more natural to me.

Comment: The first example allows you to insert more than 1 row at a time, which in your case wont matter, but you can insert more than a single row based on the WHERE criteria. The second example only inserts a single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the cardinality of the result sets.

The first statement will work regardless of how many rows in TABLE_ONE match `D.ID=666`.  Whereas the second statement will fail if more than one row is returned.

For completeness there is a third variation:

```
insert into FOO_TABLE (BEGIN, FIRST_VALUE, SECOND_VALUE, VALUE, BAR) select  
999,  
D.FIRST,  
O.SECOND,  
333,  
444  
from TABLE_ONE D 
    cross join TABLE_TWO  O
where O.ID=555
and D.ID=666
```

The Oracle optimizer is clever enough to know whether TABLE_TWO is matching on a unique key and will draw up an execution plan accordingly.

---

With regards to relative performance all variations ought to be the same.  Certainly this is what I woudl expect if both queries return a single row each.  There might be differences if TABLE_ONE returns multiple rows.  As always, when it comes to tuning queries, you would have to benchmark each approach, as execution times are sensitive to data volumes and skew.

Comment: Which one is the most performance one? I mean which method is the best, your solution is also readable but there I have know 3 options :)